# Incorrect Count returned by MongoDB (WiredTiger)

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

This sounds odd, and I hope I am doing something wrong, but my `MongoDB` collection is returning the `Count` off by one in my collection.

I have a collection with (I am sure) 359671 documents. However the `count()` command returns 359670 documents.

I am executing the `count()` command using the mongo shell:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.COLLECTION.count()
359670
```

**This is incorrect.**

It is not finding each and every document in my collection.

If I provide the following query to count, I get the correct result:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.COLLECTION.count({_id: {$exists: true}})
359671
```

I believe this is a bug in WiredTiger. As far as I am aware each document has the same definition, an _id field of an integer ranging from 0 to 359670, and a BinData field. I did not have this problem with the older storage engine (or Mongo 2, either could have caused the issue).

Is this something I have done wrong? I do not want to use the `{_id: {$exists: true}}` query as that takes 100x longer to complete.

Comment: Are you using a sharded cluster? If so, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#sharded-clusters

Comment: I am not using a sharded cluster, but thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 30):

According to this [issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19472), this behaviour can occur if mongodb experiences a hard crash and is not shut down gracefully. If not issuing any query, mongodb probably just falls back to the collected statistics.

According to the article, calling `db.COLLECTION.validate(true)` should reset the counters.

Answer (score 13):

As now stated in the doc, [`db.collection.count()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#db.collection.count) without using a query parameter, returns results based on the collection’s metadata:

> This may result in an approximate count. In particular:
>
> - On a sharded cluster, the resulting count will not correctly filter out orphaned documents.
> - After an unclean shutdown, the count may be incorrect.

When using a query parameter, as you did in the second query (`{_id: {$exists: true}}`), then it forces `count` to not use the collection's metadata, but to scan the collection instead.

---

**Starting `Mongo 4.0.3`**, `count()` is considered deprecated and the following alternatives are recommended instead:

- **[Exact count of douments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#db.collection.countDocuments):**

```js
db.collection.countDocuments({})
```

which under the hood actually performs the following "expensive", but accurate aggregation (expensive since the whole collection is scanned to count records):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: null, n: { $sum: 1 } } }])
```

- **[Approximate count of documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/#db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount):**

```js
db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount()
```

which performs exactly what `db.collection.count()` does/did (it's actually a wrapper around `count`), which uses the collection’s metadata.

This is thus almost instantaneous, but may lead to an approximate result in the particular cases mentioned above.