# MongoDB count is not returning correct number

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My timestamp property is a number (date Epoch timestamp).

Given following queries:

```
//q1
db.measurements
  .count()

//q2
db.measurements
  .find({$or: [
    { timestamp: { $exists: false } },
    { timestamp: null }
  ]})
  .count();

//q3
db.measurements
  .find({ timestamp: { $gte: new Date(2019, 9, 18).getTime() } })
  .count()

//q4
db.measurements
  .find({timestamp: { $not: { $gte: new Date(2019, 9, 18).getTime() } } })
  .count()
```

Results:

- q1: 2492699
- q2: 0
- q3: 2468987
- q4: 6

Please explain why I am not able to find the missing 23000 records. 
Is count() cached or are my indexes faulty? Perhaps my query is wrong.

Comment: Out of interest what does `db.measurements.find({ timestamp: { $lt: new Date(2019, 9, 18).getTime() } }).count()` return?

Comment: @George the same as the $not variant: 6. I included the not because it made it more obvious that I wanted the exact opposite :)

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715466/incorrect-count-returned-by-mongodb-wiredtiger) I don't know it it's any help

Comment: @George I am thinking in the same direction. Probably the metadata for the collection is giving an estimate. When searching with a filter such as .find({_id: {$exists:true}}), I am getting a way better result.

Currently revalidating my collection.

Comment: run  db.measurements.count() & db.measurements.find({}).count()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these query then check results all are the same or not.

```
db.measurements.count()

db.measurements.find({}).count()

db.measurements.find({ timestamp: { $exists: true } }).count();
```

Comment: I am marking this as the answer, because forcing the collection to be recounted by db.measurements.count({ timestamp: { $exists: true } }); gave me the correct results.
As stated before, the metadata revolving the collection was not correct and that was the reason that a regular .count was off by many records.